# Solving an 'odd' differential equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages, nonlinear

I need to solve a differential equation of the type

$\qquad \partial_{x_1}y(x_1,x_2)= y(x_1,x_1)\,y(x_1,x_2)$

with initial condition

$\qquad y(0,x_2)=x_2$.

Now if I try to solve this with NDSolve I get an error that tells me "the arguments should be ordered consistently" (`NDSolve::conarg`), here is my code:

```
s = 
  NDSolve[
    {D[y[x1, x2], x1] == y[x1, x1] y[x1, x2], y[0, x2] == x2},
    y, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]
```

On my daylong search I haven't found any helpful solution for this seemingly easy problem.

Comment: Since it's not mentioned in the question, I'll point out that the cause of the error is that the arguments of `y[x1, x1]` and `y[x1, x2]` are not the same.

Comment: The y[x1,x1] is the point of the problem, otherwise it would be trivial. Sorry, I should have clarified that. I want it to work this way.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure the meaning of the error was clear.  I wonder, what makes this problem seem easy? Is it a standard type? Are there standard methods for numerically integrating it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

This PDE can be solved symbolically.  To begin, replace `y[x1, x1]` by `f[x1]`, which `DSolve` can handle without difficulty.

```
DSolve[{D[y[x1, x2], x1] == f[x1] y[x1, x2], y[0, x2] == x2}, 
    y[x1, x2], {x1, x2}] [[1, 1]]
(* y[x1, x2] -> E^(Integrate[-f[K[1]], {K[1], 1, 0}] 
   - Integrate[-f[K[1]], {K[1], 1, x1}])*x2
```

From this solution, it is clear that `y[x1, x2]/x2` is independent of `x2`.  Consequently, `y[x1, x1]/x1 == y[x1, x2]/x2`.  Substituting this identity into the PDE then yields,

```
s = DSolve[{D[y[x1, x2], x1] == (x1/x2) y[x1, x2]^2, y[0, x2] == x2}, 
    y[x1, x2], {x1, x2}] [[1, 1]]
(* y[x1, x2] -> -((2 x2)/(-2 + x1^2)) *)

Plot3D[s//Last, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, y}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, Medium}]
```

[image]

Not surprisingly, the plot closely resembles the numerical result of [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2).  Note that this method works with this PDE for any initial condition.

**Addendum**

This solution can, if desired, be validated by back-substitution:

```
{D[y[x1, x2], x1] == y[x1, x1] y[x1, x2], y[0, x2] == x2} /. 
    y -> Function[{x1, x2}, -((2 x2)/(-2 + x1^2))]
(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Writing down f[x1], you implicitly claim it a known function, but it is not so. Therefore, your solution is built on the sand. Am I not right?

Comment: @user64494  No.  I do not claim that `f[x1]` is known, only that `y[x1, x1]` is a function only of `x1`.

Comment: @user64494  Please see the addendum just added.

Comment: OK,  Function[{x1, x2}, -((2 x2)/(-2 + x1^2))] is a solution. I still have doubts concerning your DSolving.

Answer (score 3):

One could try a iterative approach approximating `y[x1, x1]` with the previous, if the iterations converge to solution:

```
foo::div = "Error increased. Divergent?";
foo::slwcon = "Slow convergence. Error `` after `` steps.";
tol = 10^-6;
NestWhile[
 Function[{s1, s2, err1, err2, iter},
    With[{s = 
       NDSolveValue[{D[y[x1, x2], x1] == s1[x1, x1] y[x1, x2], 
         y[0, x2] == x2}, y, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]},
     {s, s1,
      Flatten[s1["ValuesOnGrid"], 1] - s @@@ Flatten[s1["Grid"], 1] //
         Abs // Max,
      err1,
      iter + 1}
     ]] @@ # &,
 {NDSolveValue[{D[y[x1, x2], x1] == 1*y[x1, x2], y[0, x2] == x2}, 
   y, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}],
  1 &,
  10., 100., 0},
 Function[{s1, s2, err1, err2, iter},
    If[err1 > err2,
     Message[foo::div]; False,
     If[err1 > tol,
      If[iter == 10, Message[foo::slwcon, err1, iter]];
      True,
      False]
     ]
    ] @@ # &,
 1, 100
 ]
s = {y -> First[%]};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[y[x1, x2] /. s, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The error is so-so:

```
Plot3D[D[y[x1, x2], x1] - y[x1, x1] y[x1, x2] /. s // Evaluate,
 {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your effort!